# How to curve a line in regression( geom smooth) in r

Tags: r

```
ggplot(data = wheatX, 
       aes(x = No.of.species, 
       y = Weight.of.weed,
       color = Treatment)) + 
   geom_point(shape = 1) + 
   scale_colour_hue(l = 50) + 
   geom_smooth(method = glm,
               se = FALSE)
```

This draws a straight line.
But the species number will decrease at somepoint. I want to make the line curve. How can I do it. Thanks[image]

Comment: [How to make a great R reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Answer (score 1):

This is going to depend on what you mean by "smooth"

One thing you can do is apply a loess curve:

`ggplot() + ... + stat_smooth(method = "loess", formula = biomass ~ numSpecies, size = 1)`

Or you can manually build a polynomial model using the regular `lm` method:

`ggplot() + ... + stat_smooth(method = "lm", formula = biomass ~ numSpecies + I(numSpecies^2), size = 1)`

You'll need to figure out the exact model you want to use for the second case, hence what I originally meant by the definition of the term "smooth"